# git commit with template message

Tags: git, git-commit, commit-message

is it possible to do a git commit and when the editor opens it is already filled with a message to be edited?

example:

`git commit "some string"`

would open the text editor with "some string" that could be edited.

Use case: I have a git alias to commit work in progress (end of the day for instance) `git commit -m ":construction: WIP"` (yes, I use emojis on some commit messages), but I would like to add some extra details sometimes.

For the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) there's:

- the `--message` flag but doesn't open the editor
- the `--template=<file>` but it uses a message template from a file

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-e|--edit` option to allow manual editing even when you provide a message on the command line:

```
$ git commit -em ":construction: WIP"
```

This and many other options are described [in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---edit)